# How to bind WPF value to a class within a class

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I am trying to bind a value to a class within a class.

```
<Textbox Text="{Binding Path=Height}" />

public partial class Test : Page
{
    Builder builder = new Builder();
    public Test()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = builder;
    }
}

public class Builder
{
    public AnotherClass Height { get; set; }
}

public class AnotherClass
{
    public String Feet { get; set; }
    public String Inches { get; set; }
}
```

I would have thought that binding to Height.Feet would then update the value within the object but the object just gets set to null.

Comment: You should write `{Binding Path=Height.Feet}` or `{Binding Path=Height.Inches}`. There is no built-in automatic conversion from string to your AnotherClass. You may however want to write a Binding Converter that does the appropriate conversion. In general, a view model object (the source of the Binding) should not store the same value in different units. Store a single value in SI units, and do the conversion in the UI.

Comment: I tried to bind to Height.Feet but that did not work.

Comment: Certainly because you did not initialize the Height property.

Answer (score 2):

You are instantiating a Builder but you do not initialize its `Height` property. That is why the binding source property is null.

It could look like

```
public AnotherClass Height { get; set; } = new AnotherClass();
```

Also initiate both properties of AnotherClass because String defaults to null.

Comment: You would also need to initialise the feet and inches properties. Shouldn't feet and inches be numeric like int or double as well?